# how to use (document.referrer) for two previous pages?

Tags: html, button, reload, back

I have a problem with the button to go to the previous page reloading data. In this, sense, if I use:

```
<button onclick="window.history.go(-2)" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</button>
```

This turn me two previous pages, but with no modification of data. The page don't reload.
If I use this:

```
<button onclick="location.replace(document.referrer);" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</button>
```

This turn me only one previous page. There is a method to turn back two pages with reloading data also?
Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

<s>I'm not sure, but try this:</s>

```
location.replace(window.history.back(-2));
```

**EDIT:**

After a bit of research and test i think it can't be achieved using history object.

Another solution would be to set some cookie or store/pass the routes available for your JS in server side.

Comment: I try this before, but with no result :(